# Generating new screenshot

Tags: java, android

This is my code. It's sharing the same old screenshot how can I delete the old screenshot and generate a new one. And also while sharing on facebook it does not adds the link i provided. it shares only screenshot on facebook on whatsapp its working fine but shares the same old pic.

```
  public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
        View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
         rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        return rootView.getDrawingCache();
}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }}
private void shareIt() {

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imagePath);
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
    String shareBody = "Can you solve this , I am stuck/n try your answer at www.shackless.shan.com";

    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Challenge via"));
}
public void shareOnWhatsapp(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
    saveBitmap(bitmap);
    shareIt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solutions i have to inValidate the drawing cache . using view.invalidate()
befre setDrawingCacheEnabled(true) .

```
  public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
        View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();

        rootView.invalidate();
        rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        return rootView.getDrawingCache();
    }
```